# How to kill android app onButtonClick

Tags: android

Actually i am trying to close this app on the click of image button but when i added a code for app close it crashes the app before it starts. This is my code. I have made app close code onCreate mothod.

```
    public class Alphabets extends Activity {

        MediaPlayer mp;
        MediaPlayer BG;
        ImageButton exit;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
            ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
            myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
            myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
            BG.setLooping(true);
            BG.setVolume(100, 100);
            BG.start();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alphabets.this, mAudio[0]);
            mp.start();
            exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
                @Override
                public void onClick(View paramView) 
              {
                    finish();          
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                }
            });
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            BG.pause();
            }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        BG.start();
        }



        private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,
                                         R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,R.raw.one,};

        private int imageArra[] =  {R.drawable.ab,R.drawable.bc,R.drawable.cd,R.drawable.de,R.drawable.ef,R.drawable.fg,R.drawable.gh,R.drawable.hi,R.drawable.ij,R.drawable.jk,R.drawable.kl,R.drawable.lm,R.drawable.mn,
                                    R.drawable.no,R.drawable.op,R.drawable.pq,R.drawable.qr,R.drawable.rs,R.drawable.st,R.drawable.tu,R.drawable.uv,R.drawable.vw,R.drawable.wx,R.drawable.xy,R.drawable.yz,R.drawable.zz};

        public  OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
            {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Alphabets.this, mAudio[arg1]);
            mp.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
            {
            }
        };

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.numbers, menu);
            return true;
        }

   }
```

Layout :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Alphabets" >

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/exit"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
         android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
         android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat :-

```
01-23 05:10:01.951: D/dalvikvm(1767): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-23 05:10:03.381: D/dalvikvm(1767): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 8% free 2495K/2692K, paused 109ms, total 114ms
01-23 05:10:03.681: I/dalvikvm-heap(1767): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.347MB for 9216012-byte allocation
01-23 05:10:03.781: D/dalvikvm(1767): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 11494K/11696K, paused 95ms, total 95ms
01-23 05:10:08.191: D/dalvikvm(1767): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 11494K/11696K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
01-23 05:10:08.331: I/dalvikvm-heap(1767): Grow heap (frag case) to 31.123MB for 20736012-byte allocation
01-23 05:10:08.361: I/dalvikvm-heap(1767): Clamp target GC heap from 33.123MB to 32.000MB
01-23 05:10:08.381: D/dalvikvm(1767): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 31744K/31948K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
01-23 05:10:10.091: D/dalvikvm(1767): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9000K, 29% free 23055K/32260K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
01-23 05:10:10.461: D/libEGL(1767): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-23 05:10:10.471: D/(1767): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8cc08f0, tid 1767
01-23 05:10:10.551: D/libEGL(1767): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-23 05:10:10.551: D/libEGL(1767): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-23 05:10:10.721: W/EGL_emulation(1767): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-23 05:10:10.821: D/OpenGLRenderer(1767): Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 05:10:13.591: D/dalvikvm(1767): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 519K, 26% free 23938K/32260K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
01-23 05:10:13.591: I/dalvikvm-heap(1767): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 9216012-byte allocation
01-23 05:10:13.631: D/dalvikvm(1767): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 26% free 23928K/32260K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
01-23 05:10:13.631: E/dalvikvm-heap(1767): Out of memory on a 9216012-byte allocation.
01-23 05:10:13.631: I/dalvikvm(1767): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-23 05:10:13.631: I/dalvikvm(1767):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2f45480 self=0xb8afe1e0
01-23 05:10:13.631: I/dalvikvm(1767):   | sysTid=1767 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1216602080
01-23 05:10:13.631: I/dalvikvm(1767):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=453 stm=90 core=0
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3293)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:453)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
01-23 05:10:13.651: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at com.android.toddlers.Alphabets.onCreate(Alphabets.java:21)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-23 05:10:13.661: I/dalvikvm(1767):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.681: D/skia(1767): --- decoder->decode returned false
01-23 05:10:13.691: D/AndroidRuntime(1767): Shutting down VM
01-23 05:10:13.691: W/dalvikvm(1767): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2f44648)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.toddlers/com.android.toddlers.Alphabets}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at com.android.toddlers.Alphabets.onCreate(Alphabets.java:21)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     ... 11 more
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     ... 23 more
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3293)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:453)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:242)
01-23 05:10:13.721: E/AndroidRuntime(1767):     ... 26 more
01-23 05:10:16.981: I/Process(1767): Sending signal. PID: 1767 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized the `ImageButton` in your `onCreate()` and to close the app just write `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` which will kill your application totally.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
    exit=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.yourid);
         ...............
    ...............
     exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) 
      {
          android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()) ;     
            
        }
    });
```

[`moveTaskToBack(boolean nonRoot)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity):

> Move the task containing this activity to the back of the activity stack. It does not close the app but application will be in background.

You might get application crashed because of the `onResume()` method where you are directly starting the `MediaPlayer` without initialization. As the `onResume()` is called before `onCreate()`. So just initialize your `MediaPlayer BG` in your `onResume()` as below:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
BG=new MediaPlayer();
}
```

Comment: @GrlsHu it still crashes the app :(

Comment: Please post your crash report in your question.

Comment: @SuRajPrince Do you have `ViewPager` in your `activity_numbers` layout file ?

Comment: @GrlsHu yes i have it. actually there are two activities activity_numbers and activity_alphabet. So i put this app close code on activity_alphabet.

Comment: @SuRajPrince That means you have written code in wrong activity Is that so ?

Comment: @SuRajPrince Have you added the compatible library in your project ? Make sure you have added `android-support-v4.jar` in your Build Path of your project.

Comment: @GrlsHu i want this close app function for both the activities. I tried on activity_alphabet not on activity_numbers

Comment: Then why you have posted the code of `activity_numbers ` ? Why creating confusion ?

Comment: @GrlsHu Sorry but I have posted code which i am getting problem.. When application crashes it gives this logcat so i posted

Comment: Its throwing error on line `ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);` i think your `imageArra` does not seems to contain anything.

Comment: @GrlsHu this app is working 100% fine if i remove the code for application close. So how it can be an error on viewpager?

Comment: Does your `Alphabets` activity start after some other activity ? @SuRajPrince I guess your issue is something else from your logcat.

Comment: @GrlsHu see i have total 3 activies in my app activity_start, activity_alphabet, activity_numbers. On activity_main i can navigate throught activity_numbers and activity_aplhabet. So now want this close or exit app option on activity_numbers & activity_alphabet. and when i am clicking on activity_alphabet from activity_main then this app is getting crashed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45896/discussion-between-grishu-and-suraj-prince)

Comment: I wonder why this answer has two downvotes even though OP has accepted the answer and even it is not a wrong answer...

Comment: @GopalRao Same question here !!! :( It may be because of the title of question differs from the actual issue of question.

Answer (score 5):

you forgot to initialize `exit` `ImageButton`. first initialize it...

```
exit = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.id_of_image_button)
exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            finish();          
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @SuRajPrince the problem is with layout xml file... can you post that?